# NotSerializableException: Expenses

Tags: exception, serializable

I cannot serialize my object. there is an exception. What am i do wrong? Please help. the class Expenses implements Serializable

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Expenses implements Serializable {
    private transient double amount;
    private transient String currency;
    private transient String product;

    public Expenses(double amount, String currency, String product){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = product+" "+amount+" "+currency;
        return result;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works: https://ideone.com/Rj5epo Perhaps you should share the code you're using to test the serialization

Comment: i'm trying to serialize HashMap<String, ArrayList<Expenses>>. and as the result i have an exception.

Comment: It still works for me: https://ideone.com/fr7ZQp Try to find the shortest piece of code that generates the error so we can test and see how it fails

Comment: it's a kind of magic)))

Comment: but now it works. i did nothing)

Comment: No problem, glad it's working now